# Viewing CSV in Firefox

Tags: firefox, csv, browser-extension

I'm working on a script that outputs CSV files, and it's a pain to try to open CSV every time I run the script to debug the next step. Is there a way to open CSV directly in FireFox. I know there's a [plugin for JSON](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/jsonview/), but couldn't find a plugin for CSV

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firefox should be able to handle CSV content without a plug-in.
What content-type are you using in your script?

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
```

Comment: @sameold is not looking for how to send headers for the CSV MIME type. The question asks for an extension to use for viewing CSVs within firefox (without needing to save & open them)

Comment: **Wrong answer**. Google send here, and title and question seems that the answer is not here: we need a plugin, not the server header. For exeample github.com show CSV as a page: the plugin do the same thing, **show CSV** in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

- for Firefox: https://github.com/okfn/mozilla-csv-viewer
- for Chrome: https://github.com/rufuspollock/chrome-csv-viewer

(I am testing and can back in 2020)

Answer (score 0):

The previously-mentioned Firefox add-on appears to be outdated. I found [another plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/csv-reader/) that might be something you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the header is served correctly, a simple preview as a text file might work directly, e.g.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/mtcars.csv

Otherwise try to put `view-source:` before the address:
`view-source:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/mtcars.csv`